# AS3 xml conversation

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

i have been challenged to take this xml file from Tomcat

```
$<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF16"><mkc><stamp><color>bronze</color><source>whatsdifferent</source><date>1313774664000</date <$/stamp><stamp><color>silver</color><source>whatsdifferent</source><date>1313775030000</date$></stamp><stamp><color>bronze</color><source>whatsdifferent</source><date>1314736005000</da$te></stamp></mkc>
```

and make it into a url where to find the image

"../images/whatsdifferent_bronze.png" 
"../images/whatsdifferent_silver.png"
etc..

in AS3.

How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you stuck on a particular issue?  Do you have code we can look at and get an idea where you might need to be guided?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by parsing the xml, like:

```
var xmldata : XML = 
<mkc>
    <stamp>
        <color>bronze</color>
        <source>whatsdifferent</source>
        <date>1313774664000</date>
    </stamp>
    <stamp>
        <color>silver</color>
        <source>whatsdifferent</source>
        <date>1313775030000</date>
    </stamp>
    <stamp>
        <color>bronze</color>
        <source>whatsdifferent</source>
        <date>1314736005000</date>
    </stamp>
</mkc>;

for each(var child : XML in xmldata.stamp){
    var url : String = "../images/"+child.source+"_"+child.color+".png";
    trace(url);
}
```